# How can I malloc a dynamic buffer from byte data with ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

Every reference I find for creating a buffer in ctypes seems to create one of static length...
Where I'm dealing with data read from a file handled by ctypes that defines inline buffers within a struct where the length is initially unknown until read.

```
import ctypes

class Buffer16(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('length', ctypes.c_ushort.__ctype_be__ ),
        ('data', ctypes.c_ubyte*0 ) # to be resized via malloc
    ]

    def __new__(cls): # not executed for some reason
        b16 = ctypes.Structure.__new__(cls) # wish I could interrupt before reading the 0-length array...
        # some unknown magic here to malloc b16.data
        return b16

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('data', ctypes.c_uint.__ctype_be__ ),
        ('buf1', Buffer16 ),
        ('buf2', Buffer16 )
    ]
```

I can easily define the data as a c_ubyte array as read from the file, and initialize the struct with `Structure.from_address(ctypes.addressof(bytedata))`...
But the problem here is `__new__` and `__init__` don't get executed, so the buffers aren't sized appropriately.

here's some test data for an example:

```
>>> bytedata = (ctypes.c_ubyte*19)(*b'\x00\x04\x18\x80\x00\x04test\x00\x07testing')
>>> 
>>> testinstance = Test.from_address(ctypes.addressof(bytedata))
>>> testinstance.data # just some dummy data which is correct
268416
>>> testinstance.buf1.length # this is correct
4
>>> testinstance.buf1.data # this should be __len__ == 4
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_0 object at 0x...>
>>> testinstance.buf2.length # this is wrong (0x7465 from b'te'), it should be 7
29797
```

Is there a better way that can inline malloc than `from_address`?
(casting is no different from `from_address` other than `testinstance[0]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to and inspiration from Mark Tolonen's answer, I realized his answer was a similar mechanic to the `ctypes.Structure.from_address()` method.

Here's my answer and tests with my updates to his:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_char, c_ushort, c_uint, POINTER, addressof

c_bushort = c_ushort.__ctype_be__
c_buint = c_uint.__ctype_be__

class Buffer16(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('length', c_bushort),
        ('data', POINTER( c_char ))
    )

    @classmethod
    def from_address(cls, addr):
        length = c_bushort.from_address( addr ).value
        data   = ( c_char*length ).from_address( addr+2 )
        return cls( length, data )

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('data', c_buint),
        ('buf1', Buffer16),
        ('buf2', Buffer16)
    )

    @classmethod
    def from_address(cls, addr):
        data = c_buint.from_address( addr )
        b1   = Buffer16.from_address( addr+4 )
        b2   = Buffer16.from_address( addr+6+b1.length )
        return cls( data, b1, b2 )

bytedata = ( c_char*19 )( *b'\x00\x04\x18\x80\x00\x04test\x00\x07testing' )
t = Test.from_address( addressof( bytedata ) )

print( t.data )
print( t.buf1.data[:t.buf1.length] )
print( t.buf2.data[:t.buf2.length] )
```

and the results:

```
>>>
268416
b'test'
b'testing'
```

Also a minor note about the enforcement of `.__ctype_be__` on `ctypes.c_uint` and `ctypes.c_ushort`...

**Not all systems use the same default endian when reading data.**

My systems in particular read data in little endian, so `b'\x00\x04\x18\x80'` returns `2149057536` when processed with `ctypes.c_uint`, rather than the expected `268416`.

Answer (score 2):

You've got variable-sized data in your structure.  How would you create this structure in C?  Typically only the last element in a structure can be an array and C allows one index beyond the end of the structure, but in this case you have two variables.

Although it can be done in `ctypes`, I'll first suggest unpacking the data as you go with the `struct` module.  If you are reading the data from a file, all you really care about is obtaining the data and the buffers and it doesn't need to be in `ctypes` format, nor do you need the lengths beyond their use reading the buffers:

```py
import struct
import io

# create a file-like byte stream
filedata = io.BytesIO(b'\x00\x04\x18\x80\x00\x04test\x00\x07testing')

data,len1 = struct.unpack('>LH',filedata.read(6))
data1 = filedata.read(len1)
len2, = struct.unpack(f'>H',filedata.read(2))
data2 = filedata.read(len2)
print(hex(data),data1,data2)
```

Output:

```
0x41880 b'test' b'testing'
```

Here's a way to do it in `ctypes` by creating a custom class definition for each structure, but is the data *really* needed in a `ctypes` format?

```py
import struct
import ctypes
import io

# Read a variable-sized Buffer16 object from the file.
# Once the length is read, declare a custom class with data of that length.
def read_Buffer16(filedata):
    length, = struct.unpack('>H',filedata.read(2))
    class Buffer16(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
        _fields_ = (('length', ctypes.c_ushort),
                    ('data', ctypes.c_char * length))
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'Buffer16({self.length}, {self.data})'
    return Buffer16(length,filedata.read(length))

# Read a variable-sized Test object from the file.
# Once the buffers are read, declare a custom class of their exact type.
def read_Test(filedata):
    data, = struct.unpack('>L',filedata.read(4))
    b1 = read_Buffer16(filedata)
    b2 = read_Buffer16(filedata)
    class Test(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
        _fields_ = (('data', ctypes.c_uint),
                    ('buf1', type(b1)),
                    ('buf2', type(b2)))
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'Test({self.data:#x}, {self.buf1}, {self.buf2})'
    return Test(data,b1,b2)

# create a file-like byte stream
filedata = io.BytesIO(b'\x00\x04\x18\x80\x00\x04test\x00\x07testing')

t = read_Test(filedata)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
Test(0x41880, Buffer16(4, b'test'), Buffer16(7, b'testing'))
```

#### Edit per comment

This might be how you'd store this file data in a C-like structure.  The variable buffers are read in, stored in an array (similar to C malloc) and its length and address are stored in the structure.  The class methods know how to read a particular structure from the file stream and return the appropriate object.  Note, however, that just like in C you can read past the end of a pointer and risk exceptions or undefined behavior.

```py
import struct
import ctypes
import io

class Buffer16(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('length', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('data', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)))

    @classmethod
    def read(cls,file):
        length, = struct.unpack('>H',file.read(2))
        data = (ctypes.c_char * length)(*file.read(length))
        return cls(length,data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Buffer16({self.data[:self.length]})'

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('data', ctypes.c_uint),
                ('buf1', Buffer16),
                ('buf2', Buffer16))

    @classmethod
    def read(cls,file):
        data, = struct.unpack('>L',file.read(4))
        b1 = Buffer16.read(file)
        b2 = Buffer16.read(file)
        return cls(data,b1,b2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Test({self.data:#x}, {self.buf1}, {self.buf2})'

# create a file-like byte stream
file = io.BytesIO(b'\x00\x04\x18\x80\x00\x04test\x00\x07testing')

t = Test.read(file)
print(t)
print(t.buf1.length)
print(t.buf1.data[:10]) # Just like in C, you can read beyond the end of the pointer
```

Output:

```
Test(0x41880, Buffer16(b'test'), Buffer16(b'testing'))
4
b'test\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: just for a fun fact, the data I'm actually working with contains 5 inline buffers per struct in an array, so `cast()` would actually work in my favor here (while combined struct size < data size) if that could be made to work. Also no it doesn't _need_ to be done with ctypes per-se, I could do it with `array.array` just fine, but since I'm working on a package module around _ctypes, I was hoping I could keep it consistent if possible. (I find it rather annoying the solution is to define multiple classes for each buffer length)

Comment: @Tcll It’s an odd structure. `ctypes` parallels C structures. To read a file in this format you’d more likely malloc the strings and store pointers in a C structure, not arrays.  You’d be better off reading the data with `struct` and storing it a regular Python object.

Comment: "you’d more likely malloc the strings and store pointers in a C structure, not arrays." This was actually initially what I was trying to do before the cobbled patch-job in the question... could I get an answer showing how to do things that way since it's more proper :+1:

Comment: excellent and interesting update, definitely a workaround, but certainly not one that feels slimy. :+1: hopefully this'll inspire others who come across this as well.